# JQuery FixedColumn Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I searched a lot for JQuery FixedColumn Plugin, I want to fix the number of columns fixed from the left side as the number we specified for FixedColumn, I have found Plugins like
[1] http://www.novasoftware.com/Download/jQuery_FixedTable/JQuery_FixedTable.aspx
[2] http://jsbin.com/uziwin/33/edit

It works well for table without rowspan but when I apply rowspan in any , its not working well, I dont get fixedColumn on left side.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

@Poonam-Gokani have you looked this one from Luke Karrys. Fixed.

```
https://github.com/lukekarrys/fixed-header-column-table
```

[Example](http://lukekarrys.github.io/fixed-header-column-table/demo.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: this link i have already visited, But after apply row span have you not that if we apply fixed-column>1 then, its layout is totally weird out.